# How to separate a command from the rest of the message in telegram bots with pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

For example in the following command

`/set first_name, last_name`

How to separate or remove `/set` from the rest of the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since commands can use only latin letters, numbers and underscores, you can separate it with the tiny regular expression, like this:

```python
    import re
    pattern = "^\/[a-zA-Z\d_]* (.*)$"
    string = "/set first_name, last_name"
    match = re.match(command_pattern , string)
    message = match.group(1)  
    # first_name, last_name
```

Another solution:

```python
string = "/set first_name, last_name"
message = " ".join(string.split(" ")[1:])
# first_name, last_name
```

*But the limitation of the last method is that it removes double spaces from the string if they existed.*